# Inserting two categories

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, customization, query-posts

I am trying to define two categories together in a post. please tell me where i am doing wrong.

```
'post_author' => $user_id,
                'post_status' => 'pending',
                'post_category' => array($_POST['cat'],$_POST['joblocation'])   
                //'taxonomy'      => 'jobtype'
                     $pid =  wp_insert_post( $post_information );
            wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $_POST['cat'], 'jobtype', false );
            wp_set_post_terms( $pid, $_POST['joblocation'], 'jobscategory', false );
```

Answer (score -1):

Just pass array with category terms in wp_set_post_terms taxonomy parameter.

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;//get the current post id
$terms = array('term1','term2');
$taxonomy = 'category';
$append = false; // or true
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append );
```